# How do I fix Hydra not working in macOS?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have already installed hydra with `brew install hydra` .

But when I run `$ hydra` in my terminal this error shows up.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libgcrypt/lib/libgcrypt.20.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/hydra
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

How do I fix this?

`brew info hydra` shows the following result.

`hydra: stable 9.0 (bottled), HEAD
Network logon cracker which supports many services
https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra
/usr/local/Cellar/hydra/9.0_1 (16 files, 1.4MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2019-10-13 at 07:55:41
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/hydra.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: libssh ✔, mysql-client ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 2,253 (30 days), 4,829 (90 days), 18,525 (365 days)
install_on_request: 2,131 (30 days), 4,562 (90 days), 17,333 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)`

Answer (score 2):

```
brew install libgcrypt
```

did the job for me.

Comment: obvious but not so obvious. great fix.